# info/information icon for apple iphone

Tags: iphone

That little "i" with a circle around it on the iPhone, like on the bottom right hand side of the screen in the Weather application, is there a way we can use that icon in the SDK?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can :

`[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight]`

OR

`[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark]`

will give you the button with this small "i".